# Ошибка если id не существует в scrollIntoView

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую код

```
    document.getElementById('full'+$(this).data('id')).scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block:    "start" 
    });
```

Но если нет id на странице появляется ошибка

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null

Как сделать, если есть id код работал, если нет то нет и без ошибок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var my_element = $('#full'+$(this).data('id'));
if(my_element.length > 0){
  my_element.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block:    "start" 
  });
}
```

или

```js
var my_element = document.getElementById('full'+$(this).data('id'));
if(my_element != undefined){
  my_element.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block:    "start" 
  });
}
```

Comment: второй подходит